# UILongPressGestureRecognizer on UITableViewCell does not work in iOS 5 and 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, ios4, long-press

I have a table view, and I use UILongPressGestureRecognizer on table view cell to show a context menu over the cell to allow user perform some extra functionality. Everything is work well in iOS 5.1, but when I test in iOS 5 and 4.3, the event is not fired.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem please help me, thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

in tableViewCell.h: add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

in tableViewCell.m

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.5;
longPressRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
longPressRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 0;
longPressRecognizer.delegate = self;

[self addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
[longPressRecognizer release];
```

// Method to handle event

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{    
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the event handler method and the code that adds the recognizer?

Comment: Hi Anna, I added code into my question.

Comment: That looks fine.  When running on 5/4.3, make sure the code to add the recognizer is actually getting called.  The issue may be in some other part of the code.

Comment: Hi Anna, I am sure that the code is called, I have tried to add "- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer", this delegate is called but handleLongPress method, I dont know why :(

Comment: After spending 1.5 days on this issue, finally I find out solution to fix this by adding UILongPressGuestureRecognizer to tableView instead of in each cell.

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending 1.5 days on this issue, I discover that somehow the tableView receives long press event but tableViewCell does not on iOS 5/4.3 . So I fixed this issue by adding UILongPressGuestureRecognizer to tableView then in the long press event handler then call tableViewCell to show the context menu, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem too. I found that long press gesture recognizer works fine only when 'delegate' property is 'NULL'. So just try to remove this line.

```
longPressRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, worked brilliantly for me in iOS5.